# Create lagged column in pandas based on a date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, lag

I have this df:

```py
  PredictionDate    U.S. 30 yr FRM  U.S. 15 yr FRM
0      2014-12-31            3.87          3.15
1      2015-01-01            3.87          3.15
2      2015-01-02            3.87          3.15
3      2015-01-03            3.87          3.15
4      2015-01-04            3.87          3.15
               ...  ... ... ...
2769    2022-07-31           5.30          4.58
2770    2022-08-01           4.99          4.26
2771    2022-08-02           4.99          4.26
2772    2022-08-03           4.99          4.26
2773    2022-08-04           4.99          4.26
```

And would like to create two new columns that contain the data for 30yr and 15yr from 30 days prior to the date for that row in the `PredictedDate` column. The output should look like this:

```py
   PredictionDate   U.S. 30 yr FRM  U.S. 15 yr FRM      30yrLag 15yrLag
0      2014-12-31            3.87           3.15        3.72  3.12
1      2015-01-01            3.87           3.15        3.72  3.12
2      2015-01-02            3.87           3.15        4.72  3.12
3      2015-01-03            3.87           3.15         .     .
4      2015-01-04            3.87           3.15         .     .
                  ... ... ... ...
20528   2022-07-31           5.30           4.58         .     .
20529   2022-08-01           4.99           4.26         .     .
20530   2022-08-02           4.99           4.26         .     .
20531   2022-08-03           4.99           4.26         .     .
20532   2022-08-04           4.99           4.26         .     .
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```py
pmms_df.set_index('PredictionDate', inplace=True)
pmms_df['30yrLag'] = pmms_df.shift(30)['U.S. 30 yr FRM'].values
pmms_df['15yrLag'] = pmms_df.shift(30)['U.S. 15 yr FRM'].values
pmms_df.reset_index(inplace = True)
```